# Use of mathematical structure on physics

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, mathematical-physics, mathematics

I want resources for studying in detail the connection between the mathematical structures of physical theories and said physical theories.

For example, i know what a Hilbert space or a principal bundle is from a mathematical point of view and i know we use them in physics but i don't have any detail as how and where we use them.

This question arose from watching prof. Frederic Schuller's lectures on the geometrical anatomy of physical theory and lots of read-throughs in wikipedia.
After all that i realised i knew about mathematical structure and about physics but not about how we use that mathematical structure in physics.

For example i know in QED we have a principal bundle with yang-mills field $ A_\mu $ and yang mills field strength $ F_{\mu\nu} $ which act as the electromagnetic 4-potential and Faraday tensor respectively but i don't know anything else about said bundle or the connection or how is this structure defined and i feel lost. I want a "tour" on the full anatomy of physical theories like QFT and general relativity. Does any such resource exist? Where can i find it if possible for free?

Comment: Perhaps The Road to Reality by Roger Penrose? Landau and Lifshitz?

Comment: You probably won't find it for free.

Comment: Penrose definitely. L&L is a lift. Also Bernard Schutz "Geometrical Methods in Mathematical Physics"

Comment: Theodore Frankel "The Geometry of Physics"